# Can a class point itself to a different address using this pointer or in other ways?

Tags: c++, this

Can a class point itself to a different address using, e.g. this pointer? I'm looking for a way of data sharing between two objects. For example, if one object is the same as the other object by value, I would delete one object and point both to the same data to save space. The following is an example code I found online that would address my issue cleanly, but it does not compile.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
  int x;
public:
  Test(int x = 0) { this->x = x; delete this;}
  void change(Test *t) { this = t; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test obj(5);
  Test *ptr = new Test (10);
  obj.change(ptr);
  obj.print();
  return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
//~>g++ -std=c++14 mm.C -o mm 
//mm.C: In member function ‘void Test::change(Test*)’:
//mm.C:10:33: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
//void change(Test *t) { this = t; }
```

Comment: `delete this` is almost always a red flag of you doing something wrong. And doing it in the constructor is *always* wrong, as that destroys the object before it's even properly constructed and initialized. The object will *always* be invalid.

Comment: You could use a `shared_ptr` for this, but this sounds like an XY problem and might not be what you really should do.

Comment: You should have a look at `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`, if you don't want duplicates of your class objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different objects cannot live in the same storage (emphasis mine):

> [[intro.object/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-9)]:
>   Unless an object is a bit-field or a subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies.
>   Two objects with overlapping lifetimes that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is nested within the other, or if at least one is a subobject of zero size and they are of different types; **otherwise, they have distinct addresses and occupy disjoint bytes of storage**.

Now, what you *actually* want to do is probably not have the objects *themselves* share the same storage location, but have the objects reference the same *data* (as you said yourself). This can be accomplished in several different ways, but the underlying idea is always that the objects you (or the users) work with provide an abstraction over the data. A popular scheme that falls into this pattern is ["copy on write"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). Also look up the [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

There is no class in the standard library that does what you want directly, so you will have to implement it yourself. (Multiple `std::shared_ptr` can refer to the same data object, but there is no inbuilt way of merging them if the data objects are equivalent, or copying the data if mutation is attempted.)

Answer (score 3):

No. The definition of "object" in C++ is "a region of storage" (ish). So your object's existence is literally tied to "where it is". That's why `this` cannot be modified.

You cannot move it. You can pretend to move it (using move semantics to efficiently transfer ownership of resources/data, then letting the original object fall out of scope), but you can't do that from inside the class itself.

Do this outside, instead, in the code that manages the object's lifetime and stuff.